# Find generated table of contents in doc/docx

Tags: java, apache-poi, docx4j

I want to find all the pages in doc/docx documents containing generated indices such as: table of contents, bibliography, index of tables/pictures.

Is it possible to accomplish this in Java? Are there any facilities for this task in docx4j/Apache POI?

Comment: You may create a sample docx which contains these and analyze it with the [Docx4J webapp](http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/PartsList.html).

Answer (score 0):

docx4j contains code for generating and updating a ToC; see https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/tree/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/toc and corresponding samples.  Updating assumes the ToC is in a content control (which is how Word does it).

As to finding the ToC, there is https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/toc/TocFinder.java

Please note you'll need some other solution for binary .doc files.

There is nothing specific for "bibliography, index of tables/pictures", but you can traverse the docx to find these.